# BootstrapVue b-table toggleDetails opens multiple row details

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have an issue with Bootstrap Vue table showDetails for row.

When I open website for the first time and I click show details button it shows details with loading state, fetch the data and then when completed shows the details.

However when I hide the expanded row and click show Details for another row, after the fetch both of them are expended. Meaning I can see details of 2 rows.

(If I open and hide X of rows, after I expand one more, all previously opened and hiden X details will be visible)

Thank you for help!

Toggle details Method:

```
 toggleDetails(item) {
  if (item._showDetails) {
    this.$set(item, '_showDetails', false)
  } else if (this.listType === MEETING_LIST_TYPE.history) {
    this.$set(item, '_showDetails', true)
  } else {
    item._showDetails = true
    item.busy = true
    this.showMeetingDetails({
      meeting: item,
      listType: this.listType
    }).then(() => {
      item.busy = false
    })
  }
}
```

Fetch method (action):

```
showMeetingDetails({ commit }, { meeting, listType }) {
  return fetchMeetingDetails(meeting).then(res => {
    commit('SET_MEETING_DETAILS', { meeting: res, listType })
  })
}
```

Mutation:

```
SET_MEETING_DETAILS(state, { listType, meeting }) {
  switch (listType) {
    case MEETING_LIST_TYPE.today:
      state.todayMeetings = state.todayMeetings.map(m =>
        m.meetingID === meeting.meetingId
          ? { ...m, ...meeting, _showDetails: true }
          : m
      )
      break
    case MEETING_LIST_TYPE.all:
      state.allMeetings = state.allMeetings.map(m =>
        m.meetingID === meeting.meetingId
          ? { ...m, ...meeting, _showDetails: true }
          : m
      )
      break
    default:
      break
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I come out with solution already. You can see below :D

Answer (score 1):

Hello I figure out the solution. :D

So the problem was with vue reactivity when I was trying to change the value for the item which was inside the list and trying to jump over vuex a bit.

**Helpful link here:**

**https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats**

To solve this problem I added mutations in my vuex for _showDetails and also busy state to show spinner when I am loading details row data. I also found out that in row item from bootstrap table, there are a lot of useful properties like index.

That all helped me to write cleaner mutations with usage of Vue.set()

Bellow my code. Probably I could still fix the methods naming ^^. If you have any ideas how to make it even simpler or cleaner I will appreciate!

Vue template (inside b-table):

```
<b-button id="detailsBtn" class="mr-2">
      <b-icon
        @click="toggleDetails(row)"
        v-if="!row.detailsShowing"
        icon="plus"
      ></b-icon>
      <b-icon v-else icon="dash" @click="toggleDetails(row)"></b-icon>
    </b-button>
```

my toggleDetails() function:

```
toggleDetails(row) {
  if (row.item._showDetails) {
    this.hideShowDetails(row, false)
  } else {
    this.showDetails(row)
  }
},
showDetails(row) {
  if (this.listType === MEETING_LIST_TYPE.history) {
    this.hideShowDetails(row, true)
  } else {
    this.TOGGLE_BUSY_MEETING({
      listType: this.listType,
      index: row.index,
      isBusy: true
    })
    this.hideShowDetails(row, true)
    this.fetchMeetingDetails({
      meeting: row.item,
      listType: this.listType,
      index: row.index
    })
  }
},
hideShowDetails(row, showDetails) {
  this.TOGGLE_MEETING_DETAILS({
    listType: this.listType,
    index: row.index,
    showDetails: showDetails
  })
}
```

My action:

```
 fetchMeetingDetails({ commit }, { meeting, listType, index }) {
  return fetchMeetingDetails(meeting).then(res => {
    commit('SET_MEETING_DETAILS', { meeting: res, listType, index })
  })
}
```

My mutations:

```
 SET_MEETING_DETAILS(state, { listType, meeting, index }) {
  Vue.set(state.meetings[listType], index, {
    ...state.meetings[listType][index],
    ...meeting,
    _showDetails: true,
    busy: false
  })
},
TOGGLE_MEETING_DETAILS(state, { listType, index, showDetails }) {
  Vue.set(state.meetings[listType], index, {
    ...state.meetings[listType][index],
    _showDetails: showDetails
  })
},
TOGGLE_BUSY_MEETING(state, { listType, index, isBusy }) {
  Vue.set(state.meetings[listType], index, {
    ...state.meetings[listType][index],
    busy: isBusy
  })
}
```

I hope someone might find it helpful! Cheers!